# formatting java script in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, formatting

I want to inject `key` into the innerHTML of a webpage through selenium
The injection script sample is `document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML="TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA";`

`key` is a variable which contains the return code

I've tried `driver.execute_script(document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = + key, ';')`

I thought this was the most logical looking way to do it but it show errors even before it runs

Comment: execute_script will take a string as a parameter.  (So you're missing quotes... but easier to just build a string var ahead of time.)

Comment: @pcalkins i dont understand what you mean, could you show mw an example ?

Comment: don't know python, but something like, var your_script = "document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML='TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA';"  then driver.execute_script(your_script);

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string as a parameter of `driver.execute_script()`

```py
key = "TOKEN_FROM_2CAPTCHA"
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").innerHTML = {key};')
```

I like to use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) but you can use string concatenation as well.

Comment: Unfortunate that didn't work in my script but that you for trying

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around that worked for me

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').style.display = 'block';")
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'g-recaptcha-response').send_keys(key)
```